# getting Spring Boot [2.7.0] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train error

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-boot-2.6.0

I am new to spring.

I was trying to upgrade spring boot version from **2.3.3.RELEASE** to **2.6.7** in existing spring batch project.

Project build completed successfully but I am getting bellow error when I run batch. Please help.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons:

- Spring Boot [2.6.7] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

Action:
Consider applying the following actions:
- Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [2.3.x, 2.4.x] .
You can find the latest Spring Boot versions here [https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn]. 
If you want to learn more about the Spring Cloud Release train compatibility, you can visit this page [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview] and check the [Release Trains] section.
If you want to disable this check, just set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]
```

My current code of **build.gradle** is as below,

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.6.7'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 11

tasks.named("bootJar") {
    archiveFileName = "${archiveBaseName.get()}.${archiveExtension.get()}"
    mainClass = 'jp.co.BatchApplication'
}

jar.archiveFileName = bootJar.archiveFileName

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:${springBootVersion}")
    implementation("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.5.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24")
    implementation('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17')
    implementation('org.seasar.doma.boot:doma-spring-boot-starter:1.4.0')
    annotationProcessor('org.seasar.doma:doma-processor:2.35.0')
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11')
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.11.2')
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    
    implementation(fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar']))
    implementation("org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.1.5.Final")
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12')
    // for r3-id-1.0.1.jar
    implementation('commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1')
    // Azure App Configuration
    implementation('com.microsoft.azure:spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-web:1.3.0')
    implementation('com.microsoft.azure:spring-cloud-azure-feature-management-web:1.3.0')

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}")
    
}

*
*
*
*
```

I guess it is not relevant to this error but I have also change DefaultBatchConfigurer class from use of MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean to JobRepositoryFactoryBean. As MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean is deprecated.

Comment: Instead of given a high jump in version number, try to give smaller jumps (ex: 2.3.3.RELEASE to latest 2.3.X release, then to 2.4.0, then to latest 2.4.X, etc.) in each jump read the release notes to see if you need to perform any code changes.

Comment: The error is quite explanatory ... Spring Cloud versions are tied to specific spring boot versions. When using Spring Cloud you cannot just upgrade Spring Boot you also need to upgrade Spring Cloud to a version that supports that Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is quite explanatory ...

```
- Spring Boot [2.6.7] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train
```

Spring Cloud versions are [tied to specific Spring Boot versions](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud). When using Spring Cloud you cannot just upgrade Spring Boot you also need to upgrade Spring Cloud to a version that supports that Spring Boot version.

As you are using some Azure Cloud dependencies you need to upgrade those to a newer version (if available) that support a Spring Cloud version that supports Spring Boot 2.6.

**Pro Tip** I would also suggest to cleanup your dependencies so you benefit, more, from the Spring Boot dependency management

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry")
    implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
    implementation('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    implementation('org.seasar.doma.boot:doma-spring-boot-starter:1.4.0')
    annotationProcessor('org.seasar.doma:doma-processor:2.35.0')
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11')
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml')
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api")
    // for Mu Client
    implementation(fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar']))
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient')
    // for r3-id-3.0.1.jar
    implementation('commons-digester:commons-digester:2.1')
    // Azure App Configuration
    implementation('com.microsoft.azure:spring-cloud-azure-appconfiguration-config-web:1.3.0')
    implementation('com.microsoft.azure:spring-cloud-azure-feature-management-web:1.3.0')

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    
}
```